# How to extract text after "-" in javascript

Tags: javascript

How to extract text after "-" in javascript.
I have variable with value "15591 - dummy text"
I want to get only dummy text after "-".
I don want to replace numbers and "-" with space

Comment: You may use split or match. I'm sure it's a multi-duplicate, can somebody find it ?

Comment: But *not* a duplicate of that :|

Comment: So many duplicates, but *I* would use `res = str.replace(/^\d+\s*-\s*/, "")` and be done with it.

Comment: The main issue - that you DID not show your effort. Just simple question without any effort. Welcome to SO anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
var s="15591 - dummy text";
var val = s.split(" - ").pop();
```